# ASP.NET Core MVC table keeps showing same number

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core-mvc

I am at a total loss. Everything seems correct. And when I look at the database, the correct number is being submitted. But when I go to list the data from the database, the `Amount` column in the database list is always the same number.

When you go to the deposit tab, the first number you put in is always the number that will be displayed. So if i enter $50, $50 will appear in the transaction tab. However, let's say if i go back and put $60. It will still say $50 in the transaction history tab, but in the database, it says $60. Why is it not displaying the number from the database?

Account controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Models;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly TransactionConnection _tc;
        private readonly UserManager<CardinalUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<CardinalUser> signInManager;
        private readonly DepositConnection _dc;

        public AccountController(TransactionConnection tc, UserManager<CardinalUser> userManager, SignInManager<CardinalUser> signInManager, DepositConnection dc)
        {
            _tc = tc;
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
            _dc = dc;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Transactions()
        {
            var results = _tc.TransactionHistory.ToList();
            return View(results);
        }

        public IActionResult Test() 
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Deposit(string Id)
        {
            var resultss = _dc.AspNetUsers.Where(s => s.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(resultss);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Deposit(DepositModel model, TransactionModel tm)
        {
            var resultss = _dc.AspNetUsers.Where(s => s.Id == model.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            int test = model.AccountBalance + userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.AccountBalance;

            tm.UserName = userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.UserName;
            string name = tm.UserName;
            tm.Description = "personal deposit";
            tm.TransactionType = "Deposit";
            tm.Amount = "$" + model.AccountBalance.ToString();

            model.AccountBalance = test;

            _tc.TransactionHistory.Add(tm);
            _tc.SaveChanges();

            _dc.AspNetUsers.Remove(resultss);
            _dc.AspNetUsers.Add(model);
            _dc.SaveChanges();

            //_dc.AspNetUsers.

            return Content("This is your info \n" + 
                $"Name: {name} \n" + 
                $"Description: {tm.Description} \n" + 
                $"type: {tm.TransactionType} \n" + 
                $"Amount {tm.Amount} \n");
        }

        public IActionResult Transfers()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Transaction view:

```
@model IEnumerable<The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Models.TransactionModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Transactions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Transactions</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
@*<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TransactionType)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionType)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>*@

<div class="container">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <table class="table table-dark">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Description</th>
                    <th scope="col">Transaction Type</th>
                    <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransactionType)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</td>
                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
</div>
```

Deposit view:

```
@model The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Models.DepositModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Deposit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Deposit</h1>

<h4>DepositModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Deposit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label hidden asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input hidden asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="AccountBalance" class="control-label">Amount</label>
                <input asp-for="AccountBalance" class="form-control" value="0" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AccountBalance" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Deposit" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Deposit model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Areas.Identity.Data;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Models
{
    public class DepositModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountBalance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Transaction model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Models
{
    public class TransactionModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Deposit `DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Models
{
    public class DepositConnection : DbContext
    {
        public DepositConnection(DbContextOptions<DepositConnection> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<DepositModel> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Transaction `DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace The_Bank_of_Cardinal.Models
{
    public class TransactionConnection : DbContext
    {
        public TransactionConnection(DbContextOptions<TransactionConnection> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<TransactionModel> TransactionHistory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image: This is the database that was saved with the correct data]

[image: This is the transaction tab that has the same numbers]

Comment: I see a lot of code above, but I find no SQL. Is this really a SQL _language_ related question? If so, show us the problem SQL. [mcve]

Comment: If you place a breakpoint line 2 of your `Transactions` action, what is stored in the `results` variable?

Comment: I suspect that the use of `UserName` as a primary key in your model `TransactionModel` is causing your issue. Somehow you have an int Id in your database, but not in your model. Have you simply try to add a property like `public int Id { get; set; }`, and remove your `[Key]` attribute on the `UserName` property? Since your three transactions have the same `UserName`, this cannot work as is.

Comment: @jarlh it's a database related problem. I posted a picture of my sql database

Comment: I couldn't read that tiny image text...

Comment: Still no SQL in the question, or in the answers.

Comment: @jarlh you can click the picture and it will zoom in, that's not its actual size. There was nothing wrong with the database. It was on the asp.net core mvc side that was the problem. I put SQL bc this problem is referring to the Microsoft SQL database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `TransactionModel` has for primary key the property `UserName`.
But you have several `TransactionModel` instances with the same `UserName` value. This is contradictory. Each `TransactionModel` primary key must be unique.

Change your `TransactionModel` class to something like:

```cs
public class TransactionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // This is the primary key.
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string TransactionType { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

The property `Id` is your primary key. It will be automatically incremented. This is by convention. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#primary-keys

Side note: The type of the property `Amount` should rather be decimal than string, so this is changed in the example above. In the same spirit, an enum would maybe be a better choice for the `TransactionType` property.

You will need of course to modify the code using the class `TransactionModel` in order to take into account its new definition.

Comment: I had suspected that to be the case. So I deleted the transaction table and recreated it with an Id column. But that still showed the same error. Then after I posted this question I thought about also showing the Id column on the transaction page to see if it's showing the record, but I left my house before I could test it out. But you're right, it showed the same record. So I made the Id column the primary key and it fixed it. I will remember that next time, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- You're using `@Html.XXXFor()` incorrectly.
- When you want to use HTML-helpers for HTML `<form>` input binding from a collection in your ViewModel you need to use `for()`, not `foreach()` and you need to the `[int index]` indexer in the `For()` expression.
- When you need to bind a *form object* / *form model* *and* pass extra data to your view, use `ViewData` for the one-way data and `Model` for the two-way data.

  - I think that ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core's view-model and form-binding system needs a re-think, as it's *just plain wrong* to require the ViewModel object to also be the bound *form model*. In my own projects I have my own extensions over ASP.NET Core to allow me to use separate types/objects cleanly.
- I can't fix your `ActionLink` items though

```
    <tbody>
@for( int i = 0; i < this.Model.Count; i++ ) {
    
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( m => m[i].UserName )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( m => m[i].Description )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( m => m[i].TransactionType )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( m => m[i].Amount )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor( m => m[i].Date )
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
```